# Pass the AlertDialog Element in Intent(Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I am Having problem after googling everywhere could not find how to store the Alert Dialog Element or Popup Element in a variable.

For Example, 
            In my Popup Window I am having values like Principal, Incharge and Teacher from json through php.

Not i would like to move the Selected Item in Intent like passing (Principal) in Intent.

I am trying hard for this. Please Help !

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Recipent:-");

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
        for (i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            arrayAdapter.add(myData[i]);
            selecteditem = myData[i]; /// Should be the selected item but its not i know
        }

        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builderInner.setMessage(strName);
                 Intent intent = new Intent(context,send_communication_to.class);
                 intent.putExtra("Authoritytype", selecteditem);
                 context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: issue is that i want to pass the selected item of pop op window for example **teacher** to next page.how can we acheive this

Comment: Why can't you use `Intent` ?

Comment: i can't understand what you want to do ,, but the stranger thing here why you put this line in for loop **selecteditem = myData[i];** ?

Comment: @AhmadAlkhateeb i know thats wrong that's why i have added a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `intent.putExtra("Authoritytype", selecteditem);`
use `intent.putExtra("Authoritytype", strName );`

the values stored in `selecteditem` is always last item in `myData` as `selecteditem` values is set inside the `for` loop

```
for (i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            arrayAdapter.add(myData[i]);
            selecteditem = myData[i]; /// Should be the selected item but its not i know
        }
```

**OR**
replace `String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);`

with

```
selecteditem = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
```

Comment: thanks a ton! i just replaced the

intent.putExtra("Authoritytype", **selecteditem**); **TO**

intent.putExtra("Authoritytype", **arrayAdapter.getItem(which)**);

and it worked for me

Comment: @TusharThurawa: I am glad that I could help you, please mark this as correct answer

Comment: yaa sure but i m not having that much reputation to vote up :-(

Comment: @TusharThurawa: Isn't there a tick sign, (i am not sure if you need enough reputation to select the tick)